# jQuery UI: combining Sortable with Draggable while cloning the Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to build an interface tool which essentially allows users to build a grid out of common UI elements.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FX4Fw/

Essentially, the idea is that you drag content elements (picture, headline, standfirst, etc) into the grey placeholder at the bottom. Once they're in there, they should no longer be Draggables (because this breaks the CSS grid system they inherit) and they can then be resized. The original items in the UI should stay where they are, so the user is essentially cloning them into the box to be positioned.

This almost works in my demo, but when the user grabs a UI element and drags it into the placeholder, I then remove the `ui-draggable` class from the cloned element that ends up inside the placeholder. This also removes it from the original source element (I want this to stay where it is) so it's no longer usable.

Is there a way to combine these things so they work in tandem? Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041887/176615

(basically this code)

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    //check it wasn't here previously
    if(!ui.item.data('tag') && !ui.item.data('handle')) {
        ui.item.data('tag', true); //tag new draggable drops
        ui.item.removeClass('ui-draggable'); // dirty hack
    }
},
```